# Is it possible to push docker images for different architectures separately?

Tags: docker, docker-buildkit, buildx

From what I know `docker buildx build --push` will overwrite existing image architectures with the one you specified in `--platform` parameter. As I understand you have to build and push for all architectures at the same time when using `buildx`. However, I know that official docker images use arm64 build farm to build linux/arm64 images. How is it possible? Do they just use `docker push` without `buildx`? If so, does it mean `docker push` doesn't overwrite existing architectures unlike `buildx`? What's the best way to do that if I want to build and push multiple architectures on separate machines?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can build and push with separate commands on different hosts in a cluster, each sending to a different tag. And then after all tags for each platform have been pushed, you can use `docker manifest` to create a multiplatform manifest that points to all images with a single tag. This tool currently requires experimental support to be enabled.

Further details on `docker manifest` can be found in the docs: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/manifest/

Comment: Do you mean I need to have different repos for multiple architectures, kinda like official images use https://hub.docker.com/r/arm64v8 and so on?

Comment: @chingis I said different tags. If you want to use different repos, that's your call.