# can you combine separate builds from docker?

Tags: docker, manifest, multiarch, buildx

I am using circleci to deploy an application, I deploy to both amd and arm architectures so my builds are multi-arch which I have been using docker buildx for. With the new arm support from circleci I was able to cut the time on this process down from sometimes 3 hours using quemu, to around 20 minutes by building both separately in their respective build environments (no need to use quemu when you build on the target arch). What I am running into is that when I run the buildx commands, one build will complete, push it's results to the repository and then the other completes and overwrites the previous. What I am trying to achieve is combining the built images into a single manifest to push together as if I built them at the same time. Is there a way to achieve what I am attempting without getting into direct modification of the manifest files? An example of the commands needed to achieve this would be extremely helpful!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options I know of.

First, you can have buildx run builds on multiple nodes, one for each platform, rather than using qemu. For that, you would use `docker buildx create --append` to add the additional nodes to the builder instance. The downside of this is you'll need the nodes accessible from the node running `docker buildx` which likely doesn't apply to ephemeral cloud build environments.

The second option is to use the experimental `docker manifest` command. Each builder would push a separate tag. And at the end of all those, you would use `docker manifest create` to build a manifest list and `docker manifest push` to push that to a registry. Since this is an experimental feature, you'll want to `export DOCKER_CLI_EXPERIMENTAL=enabled` to see it in the command line. (You can also modify `~/.docker/config.json` to have an `"experimental": "enabled"` entry.)

Comment: Thanks allot! Docker manifest was what I was looking for